# Google tasks automation don't work with time "due"

Tags: python, automation, calendar, task

I've been diving into Google Calendar automation lately, and I'm trying to set up a task creation process. However, I've hit a roadblock – when I plug in the date, things aren't working as they should. It's a bit puzzling because the code itself appears to be fine, but when I go over to Google Calendar, I'm noticing that tasks are getting generated for all sorts of dates, like every single Friday for example. I'm wondering if anyone could help me out by providing the correct task format along with the associated date? Your assistance would be really appreciated!